# How to run 2 spring boot applications in your local machine

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

In my windows 10 machine, I want to run 2 spring boot applications one at port 8084 & another at port 8081 which are basically basically 2 versions of the same application so that I can compare the behavior of older version with the newer one. In the application.yml file for the older version, I have defined the serever.port as 8084 & in newer version as 8081.I assume that both of them uses tomcat under the hood. If I were directly using tomcat, I could have made changes in server.xml. But in spring boot I do not have access to underlying tomcat. Now when I start the older version at port 8084 it starts fine. But when I start the newer version at port 8081 it gives bind exception - "Web server failed to start. Port 8084 was already in use". I am running both of them from IntelliJ

Comment: Can you share the YAMLs, the project structure, and the IntelliJ configuration for the "new version"? It seems it picks up the wrong application.yaml

Comment: Where are you specifying port 8081?

Answer (score 0):

Is this two different versions of a codebase?  Create two duplicate projects on your local machine by checking out the two versions.

Start two separate instances of IntelliJ, one for each of the two local copies.  Edit the port for one of them.  Run them in their own IntelliJ instances.

It's clumsy and repetitive, but it'll work.

I assume this is a temporary, one-time exercise that will be unnecessary once the comparison is complete.

Comment: I am already doing the things u mentioned. Created 2 duplicate projects on your local machine by checking out the two versions. But I am not running 2 separate instances of IntelliJ - only 2 windows. Should I copy my intelliJ to different folder?

Comment: Two separate instances of IntelliJ, with the project they run owning different ports.  Absolutely necessary.  Don't copy IntelliJ project files.  Create a new project for each one.

Comment: I extracted the idealC-2020.2.2.win at 2 folders - IntelliJ and IntelliJ2. Started 1st instance of IntelliJ by running D:\IntelliJ\bin\idea64.exe. It starts. Try to start the 2nd instance by clicking D:\IntelliJ2\bin\idea64.exe.It does not start the 2nd instance, rather the 1st instance which I minimized get highlighted.

Comment: Do u think I have to customize idea.properties file?

Comment: no.  I routinely run two or three separate instances of IntelliJ on a single laptop.  I don't know what "extracted the .win at 2 folders" means.  Create two separate checkouts from GitHub and set up IntelliJ for each one independently.